# error while installing programs from github

Tags: python, shell, ubuntu

I am trying to install some programs. I put them all in a text file called `requirements.txt`.
I am running this file using the following command on my Ubuntu machine:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

but it gave this error:

```
Obtaining bx-python from git+git://github.com/eranroz/bx-python#egg=bx-python (from -r requirements.txt (line 7))
  Cloning git://github.com/eranroz/bx-python to ./src/bx-python
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 140.82.118.3]: errno=Connection timed out
github.com[1: 140.82.118.4]: errno=Connection timed out

Command "git clone -q git://github.com/eranroz/bx-python /DATA/ali/src/bx-python" failed with error code 128 in None
```

do you know how I can fix the problem?

here is what I have in the `requirements.txt`:

```
numpy==1.13.3
pandas==0.23.4
scipy==1.0.0
Cython==0.28.5
scikit-learn==0.19.1
hmm_kit
-e git://github.com/eranroz/bx-python#egg=bx-python
```

Answer (score 0):

the key lines are:

```
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 140.82.118.3]: errno=Connection timed out
```

So it looks like you are timing out getting to GitHub.  Could be slowness at GitHub, but it is more likely that something is blocking you from getting there.

Can you get to github.com from that machine using a web browser, curl, wget, etc?

Comment: hmm, what happens if you change your requirements entry to be `-e git+https://github.com/eranroz/bx-python#egg=bx-python`?